# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM), expecting ')'

Tags: php

I use PHP 5.5. I try to add an arrow instead of a colon, but it still does not work. How to fix the code so that it works?
My code:

```
 function  add($a,$b){
 return $a + $b;
 }

 function div($a,$b){
    return $a / $b;
 }
$server = new soap_server();

  $server->configureWSDL("Jemix WS ","urn:http://jemiaymen.com");


  $server->register("add", 
            array('a'::'xsd:int','b'::'xsd:int'), 
            array('return'->'xsd:int'),
            // namespace
            "http://jemiaymen.com",
            // soapaction
            false,
            // style
            'rpc',
            // use
            'encoded',
            // description
            'A simple add web method');

  $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : 
  '';
  $server::service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
  ?>
```

Comment: It should be `=>`, not `::`

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Comment: `array('return'->'xsd:int'),` is also going to be a problem. Are you just throwing random stuff into the array syntax in hopes it works?

Comment: `array('a'=>'xsd:int','b'=>'xsd:int'), 
            array('return'=>'xsd:int'),`

Comment: I watch the video on YouTube and there is such a code. I do not understand very much in php

Comment: Error in this row $server=>configureWSDL("Jemix WS ","urn:http://jemiaymen.com");

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in E:\OSPanel\domains\gg\soap.php on line 12

Comment: Look, you're going to have to learn some PHP. `->` is used for some things, `=>` is used for others. Leave `$server->configureWSDL` the way it was.

Comment: ceejayoz, man, thank you!!! All work

Answer (score -1):

array('a'::'xsd:int','b'::'xsd:int'),

Your problem has occurred at above array line. please adjust the single quotes properly.

Comment: Error in this row $server=>configureWSDL("Jemix WS ","urn:jemiaymen.com");
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in E:\OSPanel\domains\gg\soap.php on line 12